# Formatting HTML into CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, nokogiri

I'm scraping a website using Ruby with Nokogiri.

This script creates a local text file, opens a URL, and writes to the file if the expression `tr td` is met. It is working fine.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

DOC_URL_FILE = "doc.csv" 

url = "http://www.SuperSecretWebSite.com"

data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))


all_data = data.xpath('//tr/td').text

File.open(DOC_URL_FILE, 'w'){|file| file.write all_data}
```

Each line has five fields which I would like to run horizontally then go to the next line after five cells are filled. The data is all there but isn't usable.

I was hoping to learn or get the code from someone that knows how to create a CSV formatting code that:

1. While the script is reading the code, dump every new td /td x5 into its own cells horizontally.
2. Go to the next line, etc.

The layout of the HTML is:

```
<tr>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>I live here 123</td>
    <td>phone ###</td>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td>Other Data</td>
</tr>
```

What the final product should look like.

```
http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot-KRnqRGrP.1361813552.png
```

current output

```
    john Smith      I live here 123  phone ### Birthday Other Data,
```

Comment: What do you meant by "not usable" ? Can you share what your current output looks like ? Also, having your objective shown as a text file would help (how it looks in Excel is not helping much). Also, be careful about this kind of work if the website is not yours, according to your legislation, it may be forbidden (at least for commercial usage).

Comment: The information this website gives is open to the public. The five fields are arbitrary and aren't in any relation to what i have put down. For example purposes and dynamics of the fields I used numbers/text.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty standard code to walk a table and extract its cells into an array of arrays. What you do with the data at that point is up to you, but it's a very easy to pass it to CSV.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>I live here 123</td>
    <td>phone ###</td>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td>Other Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Smyth</td>
    <td>I live here 456</td>
    <td>phone ###</td>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td>Other Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
EOT

data = []
doc.at('table').search('tr').each do |tr|
  data << tr.search('td').map(&:text)
end

pp data
```

Which outputs:

```
[["John Smith", "I live here 123", "phone ###", "Birthday", "Other Data"],
["John Smyth", "I live here 456", "phone ###", "Birthday", "Other Data"]]
```

The code uses `at` to locate the first `<table>`, then iterates over each `<tr>` using `search`. For each row, it iterates over the cells and extracts their text.

Nokogiri's `at` finds the first occurrence of something, and returns a Node. `search` finds all occurrences and returns a NodeSet, which acts like an array. I'm using CSS accessors, instead of XPath, for simplicity.

---

As a FYI:

```
File.open(DOC_URL_FILE, 'w'){|file| file.write all_data}
```

can be written more succinctly as:

```
File.write(DOC_URL_FILE, all_data)
```

---

> I've been working on this problem for awhile. Can you give me any more help?

*Sigh...*

Did you read the CSV documents, especially the examples? What happens if, instead of defining `data = []` we replace it with:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |data|
```

and wrap the loop with the CSV block, like:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |data|
  doc.at('table').search('tr').each do |tr|
    data << tr.search('td').map(&:text)
  end
end
```

That's not tested, but it's really that simple. Go and fiddle with that.

Comment: Thats working perfect! BUT its only posting the format in the terminal, not to an out file. Whats the correct way to export this to a text file or CSV file? When I dump this into a text file or csv, i dont get the format. EX: "File.open(DOC_URL_FILE, 'w'){|file| file.write data}" which gives me "john Smith      I live here 123  phone ### Birthday Other Data,"

Comment: I'm not going to write a complete solution for you. Read the [CSV documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), which spells it out very nicely. You just need to figure out how and where to correctly open the CSV file and change a variable in my code. BTW, your sample output is NOT CSV, it's pseudo-columnar, which won't work at all for data loading.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll re-read it. Is there any other information online that would help me?

Comment: I've been working on this problem for awhile. Can you give me any more help? I feel like I'm on the verge of getting it to format correctly.